# Android: Connect to Oracle database via username and password and present data from the database to user?

Tags: android, oracle, gps, database-connection

I'm developing a web app with Java Servlets that can access an oracle database through the Tomcat server. I am also developing an android app that I want to use to be able to display the information that is stored on this database, so I will need to provide the user with the ability to log on and access the data from the database. The information will then also have GPS coordinates to display the items on a map.

Any ideas of the method or process involved in achieving something like this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

One really easy way to solve this problem involves using another product from Oracle, Database Mobile Server.

Having your Android devices connect to Oracle Database over the network has serious security and other implications.

Instead, you can just use the local SQLite database that is built into Android. Database Mobile Server provides a sync client that runs on each Android device, and synchronizes the local database with the remote Oracle Database in the background.

You can read more about the product and download an eval copy here:
http://bit.ly/tLjaF7

Good luck with your project.

Regards

Eric, Oracle PM